# Reading from binary file in C after saving

Tags: c, binary

I'm trying to read the binary file that I created. The printing is not working, and it's printing number set (354), that's not even in the file. I'd appreciate help to my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test();

int main(void) {

FILE *f;

    f = fopen("nums.bin", "wb");

    srand(40); 

    for(int i = 0; i<20; i++) 
        fprintf(f, "%d ", rand()%1000); 
    printf("Numbers saved to file.\n");
    fclose(f);

    test();
    return 0;
}

int test() {

FILE *f;
int i=0;
    printf("The numbers in the file are...\n");
    f = fopen("nums.bin", "rb");

    fread(&i, sizeof(i), 2, f);
    printf("%d", rand()%1000);
return 0;
}
```

Everything else works as intended (numbers in file are as I want them to be etc.). There's just something wrong with the printing out of the file. Thank you

Comment: Why in the world are you printing a random number in your read logic?

Comment: You're writing a textual representation of the numbers, not plain binary

Comment: I have totally screwed up then.. It's supposed to randomize the numbers and save then as binary. And also able to read back the binary to textual numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you write number as text :

```
    fprintf(f, "%d ", rand()%1000);
```

but you read number as binary

```
fread(&i, sizeof(i), 1, f);
```

this is not compatible.

If you write with that *fprintf* you have to read using *fscanf* or equivalent with the format "%d" like when you written.

Else to read doing `fread(&i, sizeof(i), 1, f);` you have to write  like that :

```
int n = rand()%1000;

fwrite(&n, sizeof(n), 1, f);
```

---

out of that, something strange in your code :

```
printf("The numbers in the file are...\n");
...
fread(&i, sizeof(i), 2, f);
printf("%d", rand()%1000);
```

so you read a number (whatever the way) but you don't print it, you print a random value, why do you not print *i* ?

After `printf("The numbers in the file are...\n");` it seems logic to a *for* similar to the one in *main* to read values from file and print them on *stdout*

---

A proposal to write/read in binary :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void test();

int main(void)
{
  FILE *f = fopen("nums.bin", "wb");

  if (f == 0) {
    puts("cannot open file to write in");
    return -1;
  }

  srand(time(NULL)); /* practical way to have different values each time the program runs */

  for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
    int n =  rand()%1000; 

    printf("%d ", n); /* to check the read later */
    fwrite(&n, sizeof(n), 1, f);
  }
  printf(" are saved to file.\n");
  fclose(f);

  test();
  return 0;
}

void test() {
  FILE *f = fopen("nums.bin", "rb");

  if (f == 0) {
    puts("cannot open file to read in");
    return;
  }

  printf("The numbers in the file are :\n");

  for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
    int n;

    fread(&n, sizeof(n), 1, f);
    printf("%d ", n);
  }

  putchar('\n');
  fclose(f);
}
```

Example (values change each time) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall r.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
208 177 118 678 9 692 14 800 306 629 135 84 831 737 514 328 133 969 702 382  are saved to file.
The numbers in the file are :
208 177 118 678 9 692 14 800 306 629 135 84 831 737 514 328 133 969 702 382
```

Comment: I thought it would save the file as binary, the idea was to convert the numbers to binary, and being able to read the binary to plain numbers.

Comment: @Armeija you can do that, but you need to read and write on the same architecture, I mean same size of int and same little/big endian

Comment: Thanks! Now it prints just the first three numbers tho. How could it be changed to print everything that's in the binary file?

Comment: When I save the numbers to the file (the rand(), it saves "306 89 997...", but when prints the numbers out, it just prints 306 and end there.

Comment: @Armeija funny I just edited my answer to speak about that

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i<20; i++)` `fread(&i, sizeof(i), 1, f);` `fprintf(stdout, "%d", rand()%1000);` It still prints out only '306' when it should print '306 89 997 74...'

Comment: @Armeija why do you continue to not write the value you read but the result of `rand()%1000` ? Note also the _printf_ above is out of the _for_. I edited my answer, you can look at a ful proposal and execution

Comment: Ah, yea I was thinking that I would have to use the rand again when I get the numbers back, but this clearly wasn't the case. I understand you code and what you meant now. Thank you ever so much, I can finally continue my project! Sorry for disturbing you for so long!

Answer (score 0):

Your randomization initialization `srand(40)` will have no effect on the quality of your random numbers. You should usually use something like `srand(time(null))` to get something that is more "random".

Your output at the end of `test` is printing a random number, not the integer you've read before. Also, you're reading two integers in the line `fread(&i, sizeof(i), 2, f);` which will corrupt your stack.